# Using sub-select in FROM clause inside JPA @NamedQuery

Tags: sql, maven, jpa, h2, jpql

In my app I need to use @NamedQuery to find the type of the most frequent operation assigned to specific account

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"ACCOUNTOPERATION\"")
@NamedQuery(name="AccountOperation.findTypeOfMostFrequentOperation", query="" +
        "SELECT ao.type from AccountOperation ao WHERE ao.account.id = ?1 " +
        "GROUP BY ao.type HAVING COUNT(ao) = (" +
            "SELECT MAX(typeCountQuery.typeCount) " +
            "FROM (" +
                "SELECT COUNT(aop) as typeCount " +
                "FROM AccountOperation aop WHERE aop.account.id = ?1 GROUP BY aop.type" +
            ") as typeCountQuery" +
        ")"
)
public class AccountOperation {

    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private OperationType type;
...
```

Right after FROM clause at '(' character, which begins typeCountQuery's body I'm getting

> ')', ',', GROUP, HAVING, IN, WHERE or identifier expected, got '('

I've read that [JPA does not support sub-selects in the FROM clause](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL), so is there any way to rewrite SQL code to still use it in @NamedQuery?

I'm using IntelliJ IDE with H2 DB and with eclipselink and javax.persistence in dependencies.

Comment: Maybe something like `SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(type) DESC, type FROM AccountOperation GROUP BY type` ?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? Pls tag it, it is relevant for the syntax.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I use H2

Comment: Is the below answer OK for you in H2? I.e. has it fetch first clause?

Comment: @Eric IDE doesn't recognize TOP clause

Comment: Hi @FreezeBee, sorry I incorrectly assumed T-SQL would work. In that case you should also include the IDE and DB you're using - SQL statements tend to be quite different from one DB to the next.

Comment: @Eric No problem - I'm using IntelliJ with H2 DB and with eclipselink and javax.persistence in dependencies. I'm assuming that JPQL doesn't allow using anything but standard SQL so maybe using JOIN clauses magic can help?

Comment: Firstly, the info you just provided should be added to your original question for others to see/read. Secondly, I have no experience with JPQL. Maybe the answer below by Marmite might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to source](https://github.com/me3eh/java_biznesowa/blob/zad_4_zapytania/src/main/java/model/AccountOperation.java)

In JPQL, you cannot use subqueries. To resolve this issue, you need to use some keywords like ALL, ANY, which work similiar.

So in your situation it could be:

```
@NamedQuery(name="AccountOperation.findTypeOfMostFrequentOperation", query="" +
    "SELECT ao.type from AccountOperation ao WHERE ao.account.id = ?1 " +
    "GROUP BY ao.type HAVING COUNT(ao) >= ALL (" +
            "SELECT COUNT(aop) as typeCount " +
            "FROM AccountOperation aop WHERE aop.account.id = ?1 GROUP BY aop.type)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `type` with a highest `count` returns the following query

```
select type
from AccountOperation
where id = ?
group by type
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 ROWS only
```

You should be anyway avare of the existence of *ties*, i.e. more `type`s with the identical *maximal* count and should make some thought how to handle them.

I.e. in Oracle you may say `fetch first 1 ROWS WITH TIES` to get all the `type`s with tha *maximal* count.

Comment: IDE doesn't recognize fetch clause in query, so I don't know if it's allowed in JPQL